# Можно ли отключиться от базы данных для её обновления?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Я хочу сделать обновление базы данных при старте приложения, а точнее тогда, когда оно уже загружено.

Т.е. мне был уже передан через `DI` `ApplicationContext`. Могу ли я принудительно прервать соединение для обновления базы данных?

Как это сделать что бы освободить файл, т.е. что бы его можно было заменить?

Comment: вы изобретаете миграции?

Comment: нет, мне нужно что бы база данных скачалась пользователю на PC, и обновлялась только при необходимости. Т.е. рид онли база данных. И в случае запроса обновления, и его нахождения во время работы программы, закрыть на время соединение, обновить базу  (заменить), и снова открыть соединение.

Comment: почему это нельзя при старте сделать? Если появилось обновление, попросить юзера перезагрузить программу? А то так то у вас и кеши могут быть загружены и много что ещё, зависящее от БД, не только соединения.